# AWS IAM policy to restrict access to c7g.large instance only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

How do I write a poilicy to have full access to a single c7g.large ec2 instance and restrict the rest of the instances?

Comment: What do you mean by "have full access to"? Are you referring to the ability to **login** to the instance, or the ability to **launch/terminate** instances with this particular Instance Type?

Comment: yes, ability to start , stop and SSH

Answer (score 1):

The ability to **launch, start and stop an Amazon EC2 instance** is controlled via IAM using policies.

For example: [Amazon EC2: Allows starting or stopping an EC2 instance and modifying a security group, programmatically and in the console - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_ec2_instance-securitygroup.html)

However, **the ability to login to an instance via SSH** is typically controlled by [Amazon EC2 key pairs and Linux instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html). You are responsible for generating and managing the keypairs. The operating system on the instance will then verify the keypair against those stored in `~/.ssh/authorized_keypairs`. This does *not* involve AWS IAM.

However, there are two other ways to login to an instance.

You can [Connect using EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html), which uses SSH but can **send keypairs on-the-fly to the instance**. It enforces IAM permissions to control who can connect to the instance.

Alternatively, [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) **uses an agent installed on the instance** to establish a connection to the instance. It doesn't use SSH, but it provides similar functionality. The nice part is that Session Manager makes it possible to **connect to an instance in a private subnet** because the installed agent establishes an *outbound* connection that is used for communication. (Whereas SSH is only possible with publicly-exposed instances.) Session Manager also uses IAM permissions to control access.

Answer (score 0):

If its a single specific instance you want to restrict access you can use tags on the instance and reference them from the policy. [Below example](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-ec2-resource-tags/) is taken from AWS and uses uses the [built-in variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) `${aws:username}` - this allows a user to manage their own instance or you can use hard coded values/other builtin variables as you need.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:ResourceTag/UserName": "${aws:username}"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags",
        "ec2:DeleteTags"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How do I edit above so that I can assign it to a group:
I don't want to restrict by user (${aws:username})

Comment: Just change line `"ec2:ResourceTag/UserName": "${aws:username}"` to your needs.  E.g. change `UserName` to whatever tag you put on the instance, and change `${aws:username}` to some value of your choosing. Its not clear what exactly your asking so all i can provide is an example and the docs where you will find many other options. Also as John points out this policy will only grant permissions for the AWS ec2 api not to login and use the instance.